# How to customize pythonic loss functions and use longer y_true to calculate it in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I need to customize Whittaker smoother (WS) and Least trimmed squares (LTS) loss functions in keras. WS and LTS can be calculated using numpy:

```
import numpy as np


def WS_np(y_pred):
    WS = 0
    N = len(y_pred)
    for i in range(1, N - 1):
        WS += (y_pred[i - 1] - 2 * y_pred[i] + y_pred[i + 1]) ** 2
    return WS


def LTS_np(y_true, y_pred):
    LTS = 0
    M = 0
    N = len(y_pred)
    eps = np.median(abs(y_true - y_pred))
    for i in range(N):
        if abs(y_true[i] - y_pred[i]) <= eps:
            M += 1
            LTS += (y_true[i] - y_pred[i]) ** 2
    return LTS / M
```

I tried to change them into keras loss functions, the code is as follows:

```
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf


def WS(y_true, y_pred):
    n = K.int_shape(y_pred)[1]

    pred1 = y_pred[:, 0:n - 2]
    pred2 = y_pred[:, 1:n - 1]
    pred3 = y_pred[:, 2:n]

    ws = K.sum(K.square(pred1 - 2 * pred2 + pred3))

    return ws


def LTS(y_true, y_pred):
    A = K.abs(y_true - y_pred)
    eps = tf.contrib.distributions.percentile(A, 50.)

    less_equal = tf.less_equal(A, eps)
    greater = tf.greater(A, eps)

    A = tf.where(greater, A, tf.subtract(A + 1, A))
    A = tf.where(less_equal, A, tf.subtract(A, A))

    LTS = K.sum(K.square(y_true - y_pred) * A) / K.sum(A)

    return LTS
```

I have two questions:

(1) Since I have just used tensorflow, please help me to check whether the code in keras is correct and whether it can be further pythonic?

(2) Is the length of y_true and y_pred only the same as the output dimension of the last layer of the network? That is, if the last layer is

```
model.add(Dense(10))
```

Then the length of y_true and y_pred can only be 10? Can the loss function be calculated with longer y_true and y_pred, independent of Dense(10)?